# Where can I find all of the COM objects that can be created in PowerShell?

Tags: com, powershell

COM objects can be created and used in PowerShell, for example to control Microsoft Office applications:

```
$excel = New-Object -com "Excel.Application"
$excel.visible = $true
```

How can I list all of the available COM objects that can be created in PowerShell?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I found this PowerShell one-liner script that supposedly lists all COM objects.

```
gci HKLM:\Software\Classes -ea 0| ? {$_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$' -and
(gp "$($_.PSPath)\CLSID" -ea 0)} | ft PSChildName
```

Comment: I can confirm that it does list all the registered COM objects. Whether or not they implement the COM interface correctly is a whole different issue. :)

Comment: *my two cents:* `HKLM\Software\Classes`actually corresponds to `HKCR`

Comment: And my two cents: rather than piping to `ft PSChildName`, pipe to `select -ExpandProperty PSChildName`. That returns the results as an array that can be filtered with **-match** or **Select-String**.

Comment: this script above did not work for me, instead this script works: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/27/pstip-get-a-list-of-all-com-objects-available/

Comment: wben you do `Format-Text`, you will not get `string`s, but some formatting related classes

Comment: @Jeff Can you explain purpose of this filter `$_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$'`

Comment: Perfectly works in Windows 11 v23H2.

Answer (score 9):

Use OleView.exe from Microsoft. I think it may come with Visual Studio. If not, you can find it in the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx). That's a big download; you can either download the whole thing or you could experiment with downloading it piecemeal using the setup.exe installer.

Once in OleView, look under "type libraries". Excel for instance appears under "Microsoft Exel".

Comment: https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet

Answer (score 7):

Another option that should be noted is through WMI:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting
```

Comment: running this produced an infinite loop

Comment: Since it isn't a loop, it can not possibly be an infinite loop.  It will take a long time to run because there are MANY COM components.

Comment: That does not list the ActiveX control I am looking for. This does https://gist.github.com/810398

Comment: ActiveX Controls won't always have a progid, or more correctly, a programmatic identifier (which is what the scripts above are discovering in HKCR. But they always have a CLSID. If you are just trying to determine whether the ActiveX Control is installed so you can uninstall it, search for its CLSID in HKCR/CLSID.