# How to list all ActiveX controls?

Tags: com, interface, activex

Is there a way to list/browse all ActiveX controls in the system or for particular application? Can this be done from some administration screen as well as in code?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use [OLEview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx) to inspect COM/ActiveX objects on my pc as it also allows me to [inspect the interfaces](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/DotNetCollsFromNativeCode/DotNetCollectionsFromNativeCodeDemo_OleView.GIF) exposed by the objects.

A programmatic approach has been posted by [Jeff Attwood on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660319/where-can-i-find-all-of-the-com-objects-that-can-be-created-in-powershell).

Answer (score 5):

TRy this [ActiveXHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialise COM libraries
CoInitialize (NULL);

//The Component Category Manager implemented by System implements
//this interface
ICatInformation *pCatInfo=NULL;

//Create an instance of standard Component Category Manager
HRESULT hr=CoCreateInstance (CLSID_StdComponentCategoriesMgr ,
NULL,
CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
IID_ICatInformation ,
(void **)&pCatInfo);

//Increase ref count on interface
pCatInfo->AddRef ();

//IEnumGUID interface provides enumerator for enumerating through
//the collection of COM objects
IEnumGUID *pEnumGUID=NULL;

//We are intersted in finding out only controls so put CATID_Control
//in the array
CATID pcatidImpl[1];
CATID pcatidReqd[1];
// Want only my Plugin Category
pcatidImpl[0]=CATID_MyPlugin;
pcatidReqd[1]=CATID_MyPlugin;

// Want all Active X Control
//pcatidImpl[0]=CATID_Control; 


//Now enumerate the classes i.e. COM objects of this type.
pCatInfo->EnumClassesOfCategories (1,
pcatidImpl,
0,
pcatidReqd ,
&pEnumGUID);

//Enumerate as long as you get S_OK
CLSID clsid;

while( (hr= pEnumGUID->Next( 1, &clsid, NULL ))==S_OK )
{
BSTR bstrClassName; //Get the information of class

//This is what MSDN says about the parameters
/*-----------------------------------------------
USERCLASSTYPE_FULL The full type name of the class.
USERCLASSTYPE_SHORT A short name (maximum of 15 characters) that
is used for popup menus and the Links dialog
box.
USERCLASSTYPE_APPNAME The name of the application servicing the class
and is used in the Result text in dialog boxes.
-----------------------------------------------*/
OleRegGetUserType (clsid,USERCLASSTYPE_FULL,&bstrClassName);
CString strControlName(bstrClassName);
//Add string in our listbox
m_list1.AddString (strControlName);
}

//we are done so now release the interface ptr
pCatInfo->Release ();

CoUninitialize ();
```